# How to add title to the legend in this barplot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have following data and code to make this barplot:

```
tt = structure(c(21.5, 19.75, 15.05, 26.925, 19.75, NA, 28.2, 19.7, 
15.4), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("4", "6", "8"), c("3", 
"4", "5")))

tt
      3      4    5
4 21.50 26.925 28.2
6 19.75 19.750 19.7
8 15.05     NA 15.4

barplot(tt, beside=T, legend=rownames(tt))
```

[image]

I want to add a title (say "Test") to the legend box. I tried following but it does not work:

```
barplot(tt, beside=T, legend=rownames(tt), legend.text="Test")
```

also:

```
barplot(tt, beside=T, legend=rownames(tt))
legend("topright", legend="test")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: PS: NEVER EVER use `T` as short for `TRUE` again. `T` is not reserved. If you run the following line: `T <- "There I got you"` and try to make the plot again, you'll see immediately why using `T` is a dangerous idea.

Comment: @JorisMeys: Very good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the argument `args.legend` to pass extra arguments to the function `legend()`, like this:

```
barplot(tt, beside=TRUE, legend=rownames(tt),args.legend=list(title="aTitle"))
```

Gives:

[image: barplot]

Note that you can also pass other arguments of the `legend()` function in the same way, so you can adjust the appearance further with the arguments you find on the help page `?legend`.

Comment: args.legend is very useful. Thanks. I am just waiting for any other responses before accepting.